# Kubernetes pod error: creating multiple services

Tags: kubernetes, deep-learning, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud, kubernetes-ingress

I am pretty new in Kubernetese, so apologies if this my questions seem vague. I try to elaborate as much as possible. I have a pod on Google Cloud via Kubernetese that has a GPU in it. This GPU is responsible for processing one set of tasks, let's say classifying images. In order to do so, I created a service with kubernetes. The service section of my yaml file looks something the following. Also the url for this service will be `http://model-server-service.default.svc.cluster.local` since the name of the Service is `moderl-server-service`

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: model-server
  name: model-server
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: model-server
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 1
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: model-server
    spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - -t
        - "120"
        - -b
        - "0.0.0.0"
        - app:flask_app
        command:
        - gunicorn
        env:
        - name: ENV
          value: staging
        - name: GCP
          value: "2"
        image: gcr.io/my-production/my-model-server: myGitHash
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: model-server
        resources: {}
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        resources:
          limits:
           nvidia.com/gpu: 1
        ports:
          - containerPort: 8000
            protocol: TCP
        volumeMounts:
        - name: model-files
          mountPath: /model-server/models
      # These containers are run during pod initialization
      initContainers:
      - name: model-download
        image: gcr.io/my-production/my-model-server: myGitHash
        command:
        - gsutil
        - cp
        - -r
        - gs://my-staging-models/*
        - /model-files/
        volumeMounts:
        - name: model-files
          mountPath: "/model-files"
      volumes:
      - name: model-files
        emptyDir: {}
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 0
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: model-server
  name: model-server-service
  namespace: default
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8000
  selector:
    app: model-server
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
```

Here my question begins. I am creating a new set of tasks. For this new set of tasks, I will need extensive memory, so I do not want to use the previous service. I would like to do it as part of a separate new service. Something with the following url `http://model-server-heavy-service.default.svc.cluster.local`. I tried to create a new yaml file `model-server-heavy.yaml`. In this new yaml file, I changed the name of the service from `model-server-service` into `model-server-heavy-service`. Also, I changed the name of the app and name from `model-server` into `model-sever-heavy`. So the final yaml file looks like something like what I put at the end of this post. Unfortunately, the new model sever does not work and I get the following message for the new model server on kubernetes.

```
model-server-asdhjs-asd            1/1     Running            0          21m
model-server-heavy-xnshk   0/1     **CrashLoopBackOff**   8          21m
```

Can someone please shed some light on what I am doing wrong and what would be the alternative for what I have in mind? Why do I get the message **CrashLoopBackOff** for the second model server? What is it that I am not doing correctly for the second model server.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: model-server-heavy
  name: model-server-heavy
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: model-server-heavy
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 1
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: model-server-heavy
    spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - -t
        - "120"
        - -b
        - "0.0.0.0"
        - app:flask_app
        command:
        - gunicorn
        env:
        - name: ENV
          value: staging
        - name: GCP
          value: "2"
        image: gcr.io/my-production/my-model-server:mgGitHash
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: model-server-heavy
        resources: {}
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        resources:
          limits:
           nvidia.com/gpu: 1
        ports:
          - containerPort: 8000
            protocol: TCP
        volumeMounts:
        - name: model-files
          mountPath: /model-server-heavy/models
      # These containers are run during pod initialization
      initContainers:
      - name: model-download
        image: gcr.io/my-production/my-model-server:myGitHash
        command:
        - gsutil
        - cp
        - -r
        - gs://my-staging-models/*
        - /model-files/
        volumeMounts:
        - name: model-files
          mountPath: "/model-files"
      volumes:
      - name: model-files
        emptyDir: {}
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 0
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: model-server-heavy
  name: model-server-heavy-service
  namespace: default
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8000
  selector:
    app: model-server-heavy
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
```

Comment: A new yaml-file with a different name of the service, as you did, should work. What error did you get?

Comment: Here is the error:
`model-server-platelet   0/1     Init:ImagePullBackOff`

Comment: that error only means that it can not pull the image that is defined in that deployment

Comment: Do you know what could be causing this? It's fine with one service but when I add a new service, both services return error.
```model-server             0/1     Init:ImagePullBackOff
```
service 2
```model-server-platelet   0/1     Init:ImagePullBackOff ```

Comment: that is a pod error, not service error. Can you update your question with the pod spec?

Comment: @PatrickW thanks for the heads up. I just fixed the question. Hope it's more clear now.

Comment: Crashloopbackoff means the container keeps crashing, can you get the container logs? Kubectl logs -n model-server model-server-heavy-xnshk

Comment: Also, your service url should be model-server-service.model-server.svc.cluster.local

Comment: the log shows the following error `OSError: Unable to open file (unable to open file: name = 'models/diff_trains.h5', errno = 2, error message = 'No such file or directory', flags = 0, o_flags = 0)` It seems that it cannot find this model, but how come the other server can find it? Also, can you elaborate why should I change the service url from `model-server-service.default.svc.cluster.local` into `model-server-service.model-server.svc.cluster.local`

Comment: Hello. It looks for me like you have some issues with `volumeMounts`. Is this line (51):           `mountPath: /model-server-heavy/models` correct? Shouldn't it be `mountPath: /model-server/models`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @dawid-kruk and @patrick-w I had to make two modification in the `model-sever-heavy.yaml` in order for it to work.

1. Change the mountPath from `/model-server-heavy/models` into `/model-server/models`
2. In line 38 of the `model-sever-heavy.yaml` file, I should have changed the name from `model-server-heavy` into `model-sever`.

I first tried to fix the problem by applying the item 1 but it didn't work out. Then I tried the 2nd item as well and it fixed. I need to have both 1 and 2 in place in order for the server to work. I understand why I had to make change for the first item but not sure about the second one.